# is it wrong to nest several new operators when calling a constructor?

Tags: java, nested, new-operator

What I'm talking about is calling a constructor of any class like this:

```
ClassA obj = new ClassA(new ClassB(new ClassC()));
```

Assuming I only need to use the ClassA obj ,is there any reason not to do it in java?

Comment: Indeed - there are several examples for this even within the core library javaDocs, e.g. [InputStreamReader](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InputStreamReader.html): "`BufferedReader in
   = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));`". It is a common idiom.

Comment: As stated before in the answers there is nothing syntactically wrong with your approach. Just keep readability in mind. With more complex constructors it can become difficult to read the constructor statement.

Comment: The only "problem" that might be worth considering is that you bind these 3 dependencies here in this hard-coded fashion. If you want to be able to replace one of them with something else in UnitTests for the code using `obj`, you may want to do this binding in some kind of factory (or via some DI container).

Comment: There is nothing wrong in it. But, is it high-time to use/learn about builder pattern in your code?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong. Even more for some cases it's very natural to do. For example you are going to read file (old style, no nio):

```
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(
     new FileInputStream(new File("someFile.txt")));
```

You have to use those mediatory objects (File, FileInputStream) but they are required only once so you just don't assign them to separate variables but use firectly in constructor

Answer (score 1):

I have to partially contradict some of the other answers.

In general, there is indeed no problem doing so. But if some of the inner objects need to be closed or cleaned up after use, it should be made clear by all participants who bears responsibility to do so.

The examples which are given (`new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File("someFile.txt")));`) already consider that: when a `BufferedInputStream` is closed, it closes the stream it wraps (in this case the `FileInputStream`). If the "outer" object is defined to do so, it is fine. If not, special steps should be taken so that there are no resource leaks.

In your case, if `ClassB` and `ClassC` only hold data, it is fine. But if they are links to files, to network connections, to databases or whatever, you have to be careful.